# All possible permutations of a few letters with varying lengths of combination allowed

Tags: r

I want to get all possible permutations from a list of characters. Possible permutations would include 2, 3, 4, and 5-letter combinations.

My letters are:

> A,
>   R,
>   N,
>   T,
>   F,
>   G,
>   B

I am mainly looking at `permute::allPerms`, `combn`, and `combinat::permn`. But none of these seem to address the issue I am working on.

**EXPECTED RESULT**

List all possible permutations for 2-letter, 3-letter, 4-letter, 5-letter combinations. The order of the letters does not matter, therefore `AR` and `RA` would be the same and including only one of them is preferable.

`AR, AN, AT, AF, AG, AB, RN, RT, RF, RG, RB, NT, NF, NG, NB, ..., ARN, ART, ARF, ..., FGB, ARNT, ARNF, ARNG, ARNB, ..., ARNTF, ARNTG, ARNTB, ...`

Comment: those are not permutations... they are combinations because order does not matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combn` to create the combinations and the `paste` the elements within each combination as follows:

```
l <- c("A", "R", "N", "T", "F", "G", "B")
unlist(lapply(2:5, function(n) combn(l, n, paste, collapse="")))
```

output:

```
  [1] "AR"    "AN"    "AT"    "AF"    "AG"    "AB"    "RN"    "RT"    "RF"    "RG"    "RB"    "NT"    "NF"    "NG"    "NB"    "TF"    "TG"    "TB"    "FG"    "FB"   
 [21] "GB"    "ARN"   "ART"   "ARF"   "ARG"   "ARB"   "ANT"   "ANF"   "ANG"   "ANB"   "ATF"   "ATG"   "ATB"   "AFG"   "AFB"   "AGB"   "RNT"   "RNF"   "RNG"   "RNB"  
 [41] "RTF"   "RTG"   "RTB"   "RFG"   "RFB"   "RGB"   "NTF"   "NTG"   "NTB"   "NFG"   "NFB"   "NGB"   "TFG"   "TFB"   "TGB"   "FGB"   "ARNT"  "ARNF"  "ARNG"  "ARNB" 
 [61] "ARTF"  "ARTG"  "ARTB"  "ARFG"  "ARFB"  "ARGB"  "ANTF"  "ANTG"  "ANTB"  "ANFG"  "ANFB"  "ANGB"  "ATFG"  "ATFB"  "ATGB"  "AFGB"  "RNTF"  "RNTG"  "RNTB"  "RNFG" 
 [81] "RNFB"  "RNGB"  "RTFG"  "RTFB"  "RTGB"  "RFGB"  "NTFG"  "NTFB"  "NTGB"  "NFGB"  "TFGB"  "ARNTF" "ARNTG" "ARNTB" "ARNFG" "ARNFB" "ARNGB" "ARTFG" "ARTFB" "ARTGB"
[101] "ARFGB" "ANTFG" "ANTFB" "ANTGB" "ANFGB" "ATFGB" "RNTFG" "RNTFB" "RNTGB" "RNFGB" "RTFGB" "NTFGB"
```